# What is the `it()` function here doing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following snippet of code is from [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).  What is the `it()` function here doing (I'm assuming it has some conventional meaning because otherwise no context seems to be given for its meaning)?  I don't see any reference to it on angular's site.  It's also hard to google due to it's name.  The context is with regards to code testing.

```
it('should say hello', function() {
  var scopeMock = {};
  var cntl = new MyController(scopeMock);

  // Assert that username is pre-filled
  expect(scopeMock.username).toEqual('World');

  // Assert that we read new username and greet
  scopeMock.username = 'angular';
  scopeMock.sayHello();
  expect(scopeMock.greeting).toEqual('Hello angular!');
});
```

Comment: That's one of the function used for defining tests in the [Jasmine test framework](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html) and other similar ones.

Comment: `it`, `expect` and `.toEqual` here are from some test suite, not Angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "it" function do in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145304/what-does-the-it-function-do-in-this-code)

Answer (score 42):

The `it()` function is defined by the jasmine testing framework, it is not part of angular per se. You'll see it in angular's documentation because they are encouraging you (for good reason) to get in the habit of writing tests for your code, and demonstrating how the code will work in a test.

The `it()` function defines a jasmine test. It is so named because its name makes reading tests almost like reading English. The second argument to the `it()` function is itself a function, that when executed will probably run some number of `expect()` functions. `expect()` functions are used to actually test the things you "expect" to be true.

Read more about jasmine testing on the jasmine framework's website: http://jasmine.github.io/

Answer (score 8):

it is related to tests with jasmine framework, you can find more information here:
http://jasmine.github.io/
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Comment: @George, did the answer helped you? if so please accept it :)